# Resolve the not a function error in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is a screenshot of the error from Developer console in browser:

[image]

Now, I understand that the error occurs because `.suggest()` is not a function but it is being called in `ajax.js?ver=1.6.5:1287`. I don't fully understand what the errors information provided below that means. The lines `i` etc. Am I supposed to find the `.suggest()` function in `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2`?

Here is the code from `ajax.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#wpf_tags').suggest(
        window.ajaxurl + "?action=wpforo_tag_search",
        {   multiple:true,
            multipleSep: ",",
            resultsClass: 'wpf_ac_results',
            selectClass: 'wpf_ac_over',
            matchClass: 'wpf_ac_match',
            onSelect: function() {}
        }
    );
    // More code
```

This is from a WordPress plugin which works fine with the default 2019 theme. However, it throws up the error when I use it with a theme I created. I am loading jQuery version 3.3.1 in the footer of my theme. Can this be the reason for the above error?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I added the plugin to the footer of the webpage but the error still did not disappear. After that I looked at the source code of the page by pressing `Ctrl + U`. This showed me that the problematic file `ajax.js` loads on line 102. However, the suggest plugin loads on line 515.

I have no control over the source code on that page because it is generated by the WordPress plugin. How can I load these files in proper order?

Thanks.

Comment: suggest() seems to be a jQuery Plugin and not a native jQuery Function -> http://polarblau.github.io/suggest/

Comment: Thanks @d-h-e :). Maybe adding it to the wbepage make everything work. However, I still don't understand why it would not work with my theme. I don't think that WordPress adds this plugin to the JavaScript of its own themes.